# find $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}(\ln{(\cot{x})})^{\tan x}$

Tags: limits

I tried to solve it, using exponentials and L'hopital's rule, and obtained the following answer

$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\ e^{(-\sec^2(x))}-\cot x,$$
which is negative infinity.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\ln(\cot x)^{\tan x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}e^{\tan x\cdot \ln\ln\cot x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}e^\frac{\ln\ln\cot x}{\cot x}=\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}e^\frac{\ln\ln y}{y}$

Where we made the substitution $y=\cot x$ and used the fact that $\cot x\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0^+$

With L'Hospital: $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln\ln y}{y}=\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{y \ln y}=0$

So $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\ln(\cot x)^{\tan x}=e^0=1$

Comment: Isn't $(\ln\ln y)' = \frac{1}{y \ln y}$  and so $\frac{(\ln\ln y)'}{y'} = \frac{1}{y \ln y}$?

Comment: @envygrunt Thanks! Corrected.